# Multiplying two dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 data frames with 2 columns each and I would like to multiply each cell of column 2 from dataframe 1 with each cell of column 2 from dataframe 2. Also, I want that I should retain column 1 of both dataframes so that I know the multiplication is between which cells. My dataframe looks like

dataframe 1:

```
Text1  Value
ab      5
ak      6
bd      1
```

dataframe 2:

```
Text2  Value
acc     3
fnn     2
```

and I want output like this

```
Text1   Text2   Value
ab       acc      15
ab       fnn      10
ak       acc      18
ak       fnn      12
bd       acc       3
bd       fnn       2
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Base R:

```
transform(merge(cbind(dat1,id=1),cbind(dat2,id=1),by="id"),value=Value.x*Value.y,Value.x=NULL,Value.y=NULL,id=NULL)
  Text1 Text2 value
1    ab   acc    15
2    ab   fnn    10
3    ak   acc    18
4    ak   fnn    12
5    bd   acc     3
6    bd   fnn     2
```

using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
dat1%>%
  mutate(id=1)%>%
  full_join(dat2%>%mutate(id=1),by="id")%>%
  mutate(value=Value.x*Value.y)%>%
  select(Text1,Text2,value)

  Text1 Text2 value
1    ab   acc    15
2    ab   fnn    10
3    ak   acc    18
4    ak   fnn    12
5    bd   acc     3
6    bd   fnn     2
```

another base R option

```
cbind(expand.grid(Text2=dat2$Text2,Text1=dat1$Text1),value=c(dat2$Value%o%dat1$Value))
  Text2 Text1 value
1   acc    ab    15
2   fnn    ab    10
3   acc    ak    18
4   fnn    ak    12
5   acc    bd     3
6   fnn    bd     2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
CJ(Text1 = df1[,1], Text2 = df2[,1])[, Value := c(outer(df2[,2], df1[,2]))][]
#   Text1 Text2 Value
#1:    ab   acc    15
#2:    ab   fnn    10
#3:    ak   acc    18
#4:    ak   fnn    12
#5:    bd   acc     3
#6:    bd   fnn     2
```

---

If column names are not an issue, above can be made more compact

```
CJ(df1[,1], df2[,1])[, value := c(df2[,2] %o% df1[,2])][]
```

---

Or an option using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
    mutate(new = list(df2)) %>%
    unnest %>% 
    transmute(Text1, Text2, value = Value * Value1)
#  Text1 Text2 value
#1    ab   acc    15
#2    ab   fnn    10
#3    ak   acc    18
#4    ak   fnn    12
#5    bd   acc     3
#6    bd   fnn     2
```

Answer (score 0):

In case your dataframes retain the same structure as you have mentioned, the following function should do the trick for you.

```
df_multiply<-function(data1,data2){
  Text1<-Text2<-Value<-vector()
  for(i in 1:nrow(data1)){
    val1<-data1[[2]][i]
    for(j in 1:nrow(data2)){
      Text1<-c(Text1,as.character(data1[[1]][i]))
      Text2<-c(Text2,as.character(data2[[1]][j]))
      val2<-val1 * data2[[2]][j]
      Value<-c(Value,val2)
    }
  }
  res<-data.frame("Text1" = Text1,"Text2" = Text2,"Value" = Value)
  return(res)
}
```

To use the function, just use the names of your data frames as the input arguments.
For example, `df_multiply(data1 = dataframe1,data2 = dataframe2)`
Hope that helps!

Comment: You're welcome. You can save this function and use it for the future cases as well as long as your data retains the same structure.